# pandas query if dataframe colum list value have any item null

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below

```
               name            ...                         agg_data
787                 418 Media  ...                        [0.37]
799         A3 Artists Agency  ...                        [0.85]
801         A3 Artists Agency  ...                        [0.08]
808         A3 Artists Agency  ...                        [0.13]
811         A3 Artists Agency  ...                        [0.55]
...                       ...  ...                           ...
7028  Young and Profiting LLC  ...                        [0.35]
7031  Young and Profiting LLC  ...                        [0.07]
7032  Young and Profiting LLC  ...                        [0.06]
7035  Young and Profiting LLC  ...                        [0.33]
7040                Zaddy Inc  ...                        [0.15]
```

agg_data column may have value like `[0.15,null]`

I want to do query for val has lenght 2 and it has null

I tried like

```
 condition = lambda x:  any(val == '' or val is None for val in x) and len(x) == 2 

 condition = (result['agg_data'].isnull().any() &
               (len(result['agg_data'] == 2))
```

But its not working

any help
Thanks

Comment: if len =2 or =null what you want? todo write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use list comprehension with [`pandas.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.isna.html) and `any` or create helper `DataFrame` and test with [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) and [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
result = pd.DataFrame({'agg_data':[[0.37], [4,None, 7], [7, None], [None, 8]]})
print (result)
       agg_data
0        [0.37]
1  [4, None, 7]
2     [7, None]
3     [None, 8]

condition = (result['agg_data'].str.len().eq(2) & 
             [any(pd.isna(y) for y in x) for x in result['agg_data']])
print (condition)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
Name: agg_data, dtype: bool

condition = (result['agg_data'].str.len().eq(2) & 
             pd.DataFrame(result['agg_data'].to_list(), 
                          index=result.index).isna().any(axis=1))
print (condition)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
Name: agg_data, dtype: bool
```